# In a ring that is the direct product of two fields, why isn't it a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that we have the direct product of two fields, defined as: $\mathbb{F}^2 = \mathbb{F} \ \times\ \mathbb{F}$. Then, this is obviously not a field because we can take $(1,0)$, and this doesn't have a multiplicative inverse. However, I saw a mention to this today in a book, and the reasoning was:

> "$\mathbb{F} \ \times\ \mathbb{F}$ has the zero-divisor $(1,0) \neq
>  (0,0)$, hence it is not a field".

(Lectures on Rings and Modules by Joachim Lambek, pg. 17).

I am not sure what they mean by zero-divisor here nor what $(1,0) \neq
 (0,0)$ has anything to do with the direct product of fields not being a field. I always assumed there wasn't a multiplicative inverse, and that was it. Am I missing something deeper?

Comment: By "***field*** that is the direct product of two fields" I think you mean "***ring*** that is the direct product of two fields".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A zero divisor is a non-zero element $a$ of the ring for which there is some other non-zero element $b$ with $ab = 0$. For instance, in the ring of integers modulo $6$, the element $2$ is a zero divisor since $2 \cdot 3 \equiv 0 \pmod 6$.

In your example, the element $(1,0)$ is a zero divisor as $(1,0) \cdot (0,1) = (0,0)$, which is the zero element.

Fields have no zero divisors, as zero divisors are not invertible (you can prove this yourself, and you should if you are learning the material).

> Am I missing something deeper?

I wouldn't say so --- this is just another requirement, and is more or less the same thing in different words.

Comment: I am still a bit confused as to the reason the book stressed the statement $(1,0) \neq (0,0)$. Is this specifically because in a field the zero-divisor is always going to be equal to $(0,0)$? thanks!

Comment: In a field, there are no zero divisors (unless you count zero, of course)

Answer (score 2):

$(1,0)$ has a [zero-divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor) because:
$$(1,0) * (0,1)=(0,0)$$

Answer (score 2):

A zero divisor is a non-zero element for which another non-zero element can be multiplied and give zero.

That is $a,b\neq 0$ and we have $a\cdot b = 0$. The importans lies in not equal to zero because by the definition of rings and the axioms, $0\cdot a = 0$ for all $a$ and hence it must be excluded as it otherwise doesn't supply any relevant information.